# How can I integrate output from a Cake build into a TFS 2013 build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, cakebuild

We're using [cake](http://cakebuild.net) for defining our .NET builds, primarily so we can run the same build on developer stations as on the build server.  TFS 2013 is our actual CI platform; the build workflow is effectively just a `RunScript` activity which invokes powershell and runs cake via its `build.ps1` script.

The basic build is working well enough, and I'm on to having it generate reports (unit test results, coverage reports, etc).  I'd like to have these reports appear in the build's Summary screen, but at the moment the only feedback the build gives me is the console output from `cake` under the build logs.  The report files are being generated and dropped into the build's `./tst/` folder, but the contents of that folder aren't appearing anywhere in the build information.

How can I get test reports to be added to the build summary and/or information pages?

Comment: Do you mean you only have one activity "RunScript" in your build process template?

Comment: in terms of the actions executing on the agent, that's pretty much it.  The template uses the stock workflow for pre and post build steps (checkouts, gated checkin, etc).  It's a proof of concept at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

With the default build process template, when you build a test project, you will be able to get test result and code coverage (if you enable it) by default. So if you use VS Test Runner to run the tests, you can refer to the default process template.

If you need other tool to run the teats, you can add the `InvokeProcess activity` (execute the command line) to invoke the tool to test your project in build process template.

In addition, you can use the `WriteCustomSummaryInformation activity` in your workflow. The result is that you can display results, hyperlinks, and more on the build summary page.

[image]

Comment: thanks, it sounds like `WriteCustomSummaryInformation` is the key piece I'm missing